# PHP convert HTML to raw but keep breaklines

Tags: javascript, php, html

My project was running smoothly pushing the value of a `<textarea>` into PHP and the content published in social media (facebook, twitter) was exactly like the user wrote in the `<textarea>`.

Recently the client decided to implement mentions and in order for this to work I had to convert the `<textarea>` into a `<div contenteditable="true">` and instead of sending the value to PHP I started sending the HTML. Needless to say this is where the headaches started.

Written in the contenteditable:

```
One more test 
Lets go! www.google.com
#testone #testtwo
```

Sent from JS to PHP:

```
One more test&nbsp;<span></span><div><span>Lets go! www.google.com</span></div><div><span>#testone #testtwo</span></div>
```

PHP parsed & saved in DB:

```
$text = preg_replace('#\<(.+?)\>#', ' ', $text);
$text = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $text);
```

Value stored in DB:

```
One more test
    Lets go! www.google.com    #testone #testtwo
```

As you can compare, the value stored in DB & the value initially written in the `contenteditable` is not the same, thus my problem. The `contenteditable` has the css `white-space: pre-line;`.

The breaklines are not being stored properly and sometimes neither the space between words. How can I improve my PHP parse?

Comment: Looks like you need to replace the open and closing div tags with newlines, and probably change your &nbsp; replacement to a space char.

Comment: The `&nbsp;` was actually my mistake, I was just testing stuff and copy paste here.

Comment: Why replace <div> with \ n?

Comment: There's only two times where my code add's `<div>`: 1. mentions (I write something like `<div some-tag="some-value"></div>` and the other it seems like @RobRuchte suggested, when someone presses ENTER it creates a `<div>....</div>`.

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you mean,If you use a breakline in your text,Exactly the same side of the server is sent as \n and you have access,Then you can easily do the conversion any way you want,I do not understand the limitations of the subject

Comment: Maybe you can do this on the client side using JS?

Comment: "How can I improve my PHP parse?" - what does that mean? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

1. Is stored in the DB with the breaklines
2. Is shown in the contenteditable with breaklines without the use of nl2br() function
3. Is sent to Facebook & Twitter with the breaklines

When someone presses ENTER it creates a `<div>....</div>`, so I just replaced the `<div>` for the `\n` new line.

```
$text = str_replace('<div>', "\n", $text);
$text = preg_replace('#\<(.+?)\>#', ' ', $text);
$text = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

**update:**

You can use the `strip_tags` function to delete tags

**Example:**

```
$text = strip_tags('One more test&nbsp;<span></span><div><span>Lets go! www.google.com</span></div><div><span>#testone #testtwo</span></div>');
echo $text;
```

**Result:**

```
One more test&nbsp;Lets go! www.google.com#testone #testtwo
```

**Old:**

You can use the `htmlentities` function to store in the database

And then use to display the same text

**Example:**

```
$text = htmlentities('One more test&nbsp;<span></span><div><span>Lets go! www.google.com</span></div><div><span>#testone #testtwo</span></div>');
echo $text;
```

**Result:**

```
One more test&amp;nbsp;&lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;span&gt;Lets go! www.google.com&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;span&gt;#testone #testtwo&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

#### Use on page:

**If you want only the text to be displayed in the same way:**

```html
One more test&amp;nbsp;&lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;span&gt;Lets go! www.google.com&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;span&gt;#testone #testtwo&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

**If you want the code to run:**

use `html_entity_decode` function to decode

```
$result = html_entity_decode('One more test&amp;nbsp;&lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;span&gt;Lets go! www.google.com&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;span&gt;#testone #testtwo&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;');
echo $result;
```

**Results on page:**

```html
One more test&nbsp;<span></span><div><span>Lets go! www.google.com</span></div><div><span>#testone #testtwo</span></div>
```

Comment: The HTML can't be saved exactly like it is in the database, for security concerns and other issues. I must clear everything before saving in the database, but keep the breaklines. Your solution is not ideal to me.

Comment: You can use the strip_tags function to delete tags

Comment: I know, but it's limited, that's why i'm using `preg_replace('#\<(.+?)\>#', ' ', $text)`, to strip the tags but this also removes the breaklines.

Comment: There is no breakline in the text you put,The method you use does not take into account the breakline,
If you have <br /> or \ n in your text,
You can change the tags before deleting them,
For example with nl2br

Comment: Dude, look at my post.

Comment: One more test & nbsp; <span>  </span> <div> <span> Lets go! www.google.com </span> </div> <div> <span> #testone #testtwo </span> </div>
breakline Where is this text?,Maybe you know where it is because you have seen the previous text, but is it always supposed to be fixed text? If I send new text, can it still be recognized this way?

Comment: I mean the first text, what the user writes inside the `contenteditable`, it has breaklines and when sent from JS to PHP also has that same breaklines. I think I just figure it out, see my edited post. Thanks.